# Secret Santa - Revisited

Tags: code-golf

Christmas is fast approaching and along with it, arranging the annual family Secret Santa. I'd like to try and get a head start on this, but making sure couples don't buy for each other keeps causing problems and despite doing this for years there's still the problem that `Bob` is pretty rubbish at buying gifts for most of the giftees, `Erin` will likely be disappointed, but he knows that `Frank` likes Talisker, so he's a good match for him. This makes none of the existing simple solutions acceptable for my needs.

To make my life easier, your task is to write a function (or closest alternative in your language) that when given an array of arrays (or closest alternative in your chosen language), returns (or outputs) a pairing of 'gifters' to 'giftees' in the shortest possible code in bytes, such that the following conditions are met:

- Each name is paired with another, randomly selected, name from the input data (Note that it may not always be possible to randomise the output based on the provided conditions)
- Names will be provided with a list of flags that represent an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Examples) with the ordering consistent, so that column `n` refers to the same person as row `n`.
- If the conditions cannot be met, return something falsy in your language.
- If there are multiple solutions, your program must be able to generate them all if run many times.

You can assume you will never be presented with duplicate names as we need to be able to tell which family member is which, but you may be presented with data that includes spaces to differentiate `Bob Senior` from `Bob Junior`! It should complete all the supplied test cases within an hour  for pretty large families, such as 100 unique names in the source data (please see the example data sets below, you must be able to parse all of these within the allocated time).

### Example input:

```js
santa([
    ["Alice", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ["Bob",   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ["Carla", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Dan",   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Erin",  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Frank", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ["Gary",  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]);
// might return something like:
[
    ["Alice", "Erin"],
    ["Bob", "Frank"],
    ["Carla", "Alice"],
    ["Dan", "Gary"],
    ["Erin", "Bob"],
    ["Frank", "Dan"],
    ["Gary", "Carla"]
]
```

```js
santa([
    ["Alice", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ["Bob",   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ["Carla", 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    ["Dan",   0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    ["Erin",  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    ["Frank", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]);
false
```

```js
santa([
    ["Alice", 0, 1, 1],
    ["Bob",   1, 0, 1],
    ["Carla", 1, 1, 0]
]);
[
    ["Alice", "Bob"],
    ["Bob", "Carla"],
    ["Carla", "Alice"]
]
```

Depending on language, input can be in other formats, for instance details on `STDIN` *could* be provided as:

```sh
script <<< 'Alice,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
Bob,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
Carla,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
Dan,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
Erin,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
Frank,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
Gary,1,1,1,1,1,1,0'
```

Output can also be provided in any sensible format, whichever is easiest for your language. Acceptable formats include an array of arrays (as above) or perhaps a hash/`Object`/associative array or even just printing the parings to `STDOUT`:

```
Alice:Dan
Bob:Erin
Carla:Bob
Dan:Alice
Erin:Frank
Frank:Carla
```

If in doubt, please ask and provide examples of required input format and expected output format with your answer.

[Reference JavaScript implementation](https://gist.github.com/dom111/4a4ede77f44c46c5d968).

Larger data sets: [100](https://gist.github.com/dom111/b59f4d309904e666b93c), [100](https://gist.github.com/dom111/63a6c61cd8720d7b12c4), [200](https://gist.github.com/dom111/dc9ba64857d5c35b1de2), [200 - many solutions](https://gist.github.com/dom111/ded692d1e9e645f92356), [200 - only one solution](https://gist.github.com/dom111/88721959d94b22c32f63).

Reference implementation completes all these in <4s on my machine.

Above sets generated with [this script](https://gist.github.com/dom111/29d93b256058dcc7a329).

Comment: Are we to assume the subarrays' elements are in the same order as the parent array's? And that `1` in the kth subarray's (n+1)th element means that the kth person can give to the nth person?

Comment: @msh210 Indeed, apologies for not being verbose, I'll update the question to confirm.

Comment: In the first example, where does it provide a mapping from `Bob` to `Erin`? I just see one from `Erin` to `Bob`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Ahhh, that's an excellent question and one that can only be answered by an edit... Apologies! Fixed!

Comment: Can we output all solutions for a single run of the function?

Comment: @Dendrobium when this was in the sandbox I did think about having a bonus task to produce all combinations. I'd envisioned it as an optional parameter to pas to the function though so if `arg1` is `truthy`, return all combinations, else return a randomly selected solution. What do you think?

Comment: *It should complete within an hour for pretty large families, such as 100 unique names in the source data.* I just read that part. Do you happen to have such a test case?

Comment: @Dennis larger data sets added, I doubt you'll have any problems. :)

Comment: Do we have to finish in time for arbitrary 100x100 cases or just these? For example, the JS answer's approach of returning all possible pairings would return 9.332621544394415e+155 pairings for the extreme case of **aij = (i != j)**.

Comment: @Dennis the time-limit is mostly just to prevent theoretical solutions that won't finish until after Christmas! I hadn't considered that some solutions would take an I feasibly long time, but a time limit was advised in the sandbox, do you think I should clarify? Also, that's a big array, I window how Chrome would fare with that...

Comment: Estimates say that there are 1e82 atoms in the observable universe, so... badly. If the time limit is only for the test cases in your post, that's one thing. I envision that most approaches would perform poorly for some edge cases, so verifying whether a given one would work for *all* 100x100 inputs should be quite difficult. And no, my approach wouldn't finish until after Christmas (or any other Christmas) for the large test cases.

Comment: N0! It is way to early for Christmas! This should be secret Turkey who gives out presents.

Comment: @Dennis, is it worth me generating, say, all 1s or only one solution for data sets of that size? Apologies if this is working out too complicated, but any advice on how to clarify would be much appreciated!

Comment: @DomHastings Having more test cases (e.g., mostly 1's, mostly 0's, many 1's but no solutions), and specifying that the submissions have to finish within an hour *only for the given test cases* would make it a lot easier to determine whether a given submission is valid or not.

Comment: @Dennis I think only completing the supplied test cases is fine. I've added two more, one with all `1`s and one with a single solution. Thanks for your help nailing this down!

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, 191

This solution returns all possible pairings as a list of list of pairs:

```
f=l=>(h=l=>l.length,n=l.map(i=>i.shift()),o=[],(r=s=>(g=h(s))<h(n)?l[g].map((e,x)=>e&&r([...s,x])):o.push([...s]))([]),o.filter(i=>h([...new Set(i)])==h(n)).map(l=>l.map((t,f)=>[n[f],n[t]])))
```

Example run:

```
>> example = f([
    ["Alice", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ["Bob",   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ["Carla", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Dan",   1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Erin",  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ["Frank", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ["Gary",  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

<< Array [ Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], Array[7], 26 more… ]

>> example[0]

<< Array [ "Alice:Carla", "Bob:Frank", "Carla:Alice", "Dan:Bob", "Erin:Gary", "Frank:Dan", "Gary:Erin" ]
```

Comment: I think that based on the larger test cases, this will fail because it generates all the permutations... Are you able to validate it finishes for the larger sets on your machine? Thanks! Apologies that these larger sets weren't there at first.